# odoo filter one2many list

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I have a long one2many list and want to show only a subset of this to the user, based on filters that the user may set.

My **current approach** is to have the original one2many field with all records, and another filtered one2many field.
I compute the filtered list by selecting the subset that is not filtered from the original list.
Further I apply the changes from the filtered list to the original list. So I search for new records in the list and create those as well in the original list. I search for deleted records and delete them from the original list.

This approach works actually, but it requires a bunch of code and only mimics what I would expect from either some native Odoo features or a filterable one2many widget.

Sadly all **other approaches** I tried did not work:

- Searching in one2many lists does not work (e.g. setting `search_default_` values in the context). I think it is not supported.
- Using a domain to filter the second one2many list does not work (neither in xml nor python code). I think Odoo only allows this for many2many.
- I would like to create a filterable one2many widget by extending the normal one. However I don't understand where in the js code the list is populated.

So question is: Is there an easier solution than my current approach to filter a one2many field with native Odoo features?
Or can you help me with the js code of a custom one2many widget to only show a subset of items? For instance, which method is called when the list is populated and in which field are the ids of the items?

**Example**

I want in my model something as the following:

```
# This is the original list, with all entries
schedule_entry_ids =
    fields.One2many('mymodule.schedule_entry', 'schedule_id', string="Entries")

# This is the filtered list, to be used in the view
# Note: Sadly using the domain here does not work. It always shows all entries. But I hope you get the idea what I want to accomplish.
filtered_schedule_entry_ids =
    fields.One2many('mymodule.schedule_entry', string="Filtered Entries", related='schedule_entry_ids', domain='[("phase_id", "=", filter_phase_id)]')

# This is the field that defines the filter
filter_phase_id =
    fields.Many2one('mymodule.phase', string="Phase Filter")
```

Sadly using the domain filter does not work, so my approach at the moment is to create the filtered field as a computed field 'by hand':

```
filtered_schedule_entry_ids =
    fields.One2many('mymodule.schedule_entry', string="Filtered Entries", compute='_compute_filter', inverse='_inverse_filter')

@api.onchange('filter_phase_id', 'schedule_entry_ids')
def _compute_filter(self):
    # Populate the filtered list with the elements from the original list, for which the filter condition holds

def _inverse_filter(self):
    # Remove elements from the original list if they should be present in the filtered list but aren't anymore (elements have been deleted from the filtered list).
    # For all new elements in the filtered list, create a new element in the original list (elements have been created)
```

Comment: Please share with us some code to get a better understanding.

Comment: I added some code snippets

Comment: Did you try placed `filter_phase_id` before `filtered_schedule_entry_ids`, other option is defining the domain in .xml definition, and in similar way placing `filter_phase_id` before `filtered_schedule_entry_ids`.

Comment: The order does not make a difference. Setting the domain in xml does not work for one2many fields

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the tricks you mentioned with the same result...

The only workarounds (wich works!) I found is explained below:

1- You can use compute in ..._ids field definition
and put all the 'filtering stuff' in the def
but all lines on 'many' side will be read-only 
(it's a problem for me because I need to edit these lines

2- You can define a new computed boolean field on the table wich is 
on the "many" side (in your case 'mymodule.schedule_entry') and put 
the 'filtering stuff' in the def. It works perfectly and the lines are editable !